# How to automatically apply material primary and accent colors to dialog

Tags: java, android, material-design

I have custom theme with changed primary and accent colors. But `AlertDialog` is not picking up those colors automatically when I create dialog using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

This is what I get - dialog with default colors:

[image: Default theme]

And this is what I would like to have - dialog with custom colors:

[image]

I can create custom `AlertDialog` theme and apply it during `AlertDialog` creation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog);
```

I would like to skip calling constructor with theme parameter.

Is there a way to force custom colors on all themes without deriving them in styles, including `AlertDialog` base theme?

Minimup API level I have to support is 15.

---

My activity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog();
    }

    public void dialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Dialog");
        builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ...");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

My customized style

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: As a compromise, you could set up [`android:alertDialogTheme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#alertDialogTheme) in your app's theme. You'll still have to make it point to a style/theme with your own primary colours, but at least you can skip explicitly supplying it to the constructor. Since you already have one, it would look something like `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>`.

Comment: @MH. Interesting `android:alertDialogTheme` does not work, but `alertDialogTheme` does.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me. The v7 `AlertDialog` probably resolves its own `R.attr.alertDialogTheme` rather than `android.R.attr.alertDialogTheme`, because otherwise it wouldn't be compatible with API level 7-11 (the attribute wasn't introduced until API level 11). Anyways, based on the accepted answer it seems you're good to go again. :)

Comment: @MH. Yes, I am good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in your the App theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- your style -->
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
```

And then,

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```